# Fusible resistor

Tags: resistors, schematics, symbol, fusible-resistor

I'm currently working on an assessment for the electronics part of my PEO and have to complete a resistor report, detailing different types of resistor and their circuit symbols.

I have managed to find the circuit symbols for all apart from a fusible resistor, and was wondering if it was the same as a metal film resistor as it seems to just be a fused version of that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen regular thin film resistors used as fuses in commercial products, so it's not unheard of to use a thin film resistor not sold as "fusible" as a fuse.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a symbol used by [Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/48004/_ac-cs_fusible_wirewound_safety_resistor.pdf):

[image]

Some others use a simple block with some descriptive text, or the block with Z lines through it.

If you need to conform to a specific schematic drafting standard, you should try to find what symbol (if any) is prescribed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

They can be treated as fuses, here's a list of possible symbols